# (typedef) typename iterator are not working in c++,qt

Tags: c++, qt, templates, linked-list, typename

I saw already many solved problem with iterator and typedef and typename. No of answers helped me.

I tried already without anything and

```
typename QLinkedList<T>::iterator iter = TList->begin();
```

and

```
typedef typename QLinkedList<T>::iterator iter = TList->begin();
```

whole Template:

```
template <class T>
void DataManager::saveObject(QLinkedList<T> * TList) {
    QFile * pFile;
    // choose a file in case of class
    if( typeid(T) == typeid(Medium) ) pFile = &fileMedium;
    else                              pFile = &filePerson;
    // open the choosen file
    pFile->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Truncate);
    // open the textSteam to write
    textStream.setDevice(&filePerson);
    // write each information to the textstream/file
    if(!TList->isEmpty())
        // set iterator                         
        typename QLinkedList<T>::iterator iter = TList->begin();
        while(iter != TList->end()) {    // <--- Err: not declared !
            textStream << iter->getDataInCSV();
            ++iter; //move iterator to next
        }
   // close the file
   pFile->close();
}
```

error:

```
    error: 'iter' was not declared in this scope
     while(iter != TList->end()) {
           ^
```

Comment: You used the `typename` keyword in the wrong place, it would be `QLinkedList<T>::typename iterator iter = TList->begin();` (but I agree with the answers that use `auto` instead)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `typedef` in a variable declaration.

You don't need to use `typename` either, since you are not *defining* a type that is dependent on another type specified by a template parameter.

You are simply trying to declare a variable of an *existing* type, so just use that type as-is, eg:

```
// use a const_iterator to avoid detach-ing the list while iterating...
QLinkedList<T>::const_iterator iter = TList->cbegin();
```

Or, if you are using C++11 or later, you can simplify that to this:

```
auto iter = TList->cbegin();
```

Either way, you are getting the "not declared in this scope" error because you do not have a pair of braces on your `if` block:

```
if(!TList->isEmpty())
{ // <-- add this!
    // set iterator                         
    QLinkedList<T>::const_iterator iter = TList->cbegin();
    // or: auto iter = TList->cbegin();
    while(iter != TList->cend()) {
        textStream << iter->getDataInCSV();
        ++iter; //move iterator to next
    }
} // <-- add this!
```

Without the extra braces, your original code is functionally identical to this:

```
if(!TList->isEmpty()) {
    // set iterator                         
    QLinkedList<T>::iterator iter = TList->begin();
}
while(iter != TList->end()) {    // <--- iter is not in scope here!
    textStream << iter->getDataInCSV();
    ++iter; //move iterator to next
}
```

As you can see, the `while` loop is not in the body of the `if` statement, so the `iter` variable is indeed not in scope for the `while` loop to use.

If you are using C++11 or later, consider using a [ranged-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) instead, then you don't have to deal with an iterator at all:

```
// write each information to the textstream/file
for (const T &item : qAsConst(*TList)) {
    textStream << item.getDataInCSV();
}
```

Or:

```
// write each information to the textstream/file
for (const auto &item : qAsConst(*TList)) {
    textStream << item.getDataInCSV();
}
```

Alternatively, you can use Qt's own `foreach` extension:

```
// write each information to the textstream/file
foreach (const T &item, *TList)
    textStream << item.getDataInCSV();
```

---

On a side note, Qt containers implement copy-on-write semantics via reference counting, so they are very efficient to pass around by value, you don't need to pass them around by pointer, eg:

```
void DataManager::saveObject(QLinkedList<T> TList)
```

Though I probably would have used a `const` reference instead, as that is the preferred way to pass around an object that you are not going to modify:

```
void DataManager::saveObject(const QLinkedList<T> &TList)
```

Comment: Iterating the list that way will cause it to detach and thus deep-copy. Use `qAsConst(*TList)` instead.

Comment: @KubaOber I'm not a Qt user, and I do see where the Qt documentation warns about a ranged-based for loop MAY detach data in a Qt container, but I don't really see how this would be true. A range-based for loop doesn't make a copy of the input expression, it makes a reference to the result of the expression, and then iterates the referenced object. So in this case, shouldn't it iterate the original list directly, not a detached copy of the list? Where is the detach performed exactly?

Comment: It doesn't make a copy, but `QContainerType<T>::begin()` may, as would any non-const method of `QContainerType` -- and range-based for invokes it! A non-const list is iterated, and the access to any of the iterator-producing non-const methods causes a detach. A detach implies a deep copy if there's more than one reference held to the container anywhere. Using a const reference or a pointer to a const list will of course sidestep it.

Comment: Qt's `foreach` [*explicitly takes a copy*](https://www.kdab.com/goodbye-q_foreach/), and is a seriously bad idea. It's never an alternative to range-for. It absolutely should not be recommended in any new code, and is due to be deprecated soon.

Comment: @KubaOber according to [Qt's own documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#the-foreach-keyword): "*If in doubt, **prefer foreach for Qt containers**, and range based for for STL ones.*"

Comment: Their documentation sucks :(

Comment: @KubaOber Like I said, I'm not a Qt user, so I wouldn't know the *quality* of the documentation. On the other hand, the page you linked so says `foreach` MAY be deprecated in Qt 5.9, but the documentation I linked to is for Qt 5.11, where `foreach` is still recommended. Oh well...

Answer (score 1):

1. You're not modifying the list - thus take it by a const reference. You also don't need to worry about the exact type of the container. Any STL-compatible container will do.
2. Use `std::is_same` instead of `typeid`.
3. The `textStream` class member always uses the `filePerson` file. The `pFile` is never used for anything. That's most likely a bug.
4. It is incorrect to use an existing file - you essentially use it for file name storage, and it won't assure that the data won't be corrupted should the saving fail. Use `QSaveFile` instead.
5. The file stores text data and must be opened in text mode.

A proper implementation would look as follows - note the complete signature.

```
#include <type_traits>

// Returns true upon success, false upon failure
template <class T> bool DataManager::saveObject(const T& data) const {
   using value_type = typename T::value_type;
   bool const isMedium = std::is_same<value_type, Medium>::value;
   bool const isPerson = std::is_same<value_type, Person>::value;
   static_assert(isMedium || isPerson,
            "The data must be of either Medium or Person type");
   const QFileDevice &aFile = isMedium ? fileMedium : filePerson;
   Q_ASSERT_X(!aFile.isOpen(), "saveObject", "The file must not be open");
   QSaveFile file(aFile.fileName());
   if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
      return false;
   {
      QTextStream stream(&file);
      for (auto &item : data)
         stream << item;
      stream.flush();
      if (stream.status() != QTextStream::Ok)
         return false;
   }
   return file.commit();
}
```